# how to get user profile in included template?

Tags: django

Can i get the user profile/img in login.html using user? I want to load the login module in all of my page. Whats the best practice for including template?

model

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    User = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    ProfImg = models.FileField(upload_to='images')
    UserName = models.CharField(max_length=50)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.UserName
```

base.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
</head>
<body>
{% include '/login.html' %}
</body>
</html>
```

login.html

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <div class ="profile-info">
        <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ request.user.get_profile.ProfImg }}" width = "150" height = "150"  />
        Welcome {{ request.user.get_profile.UserName }}               
       <p>You last logged in on Tuesday the 19th of March, 2013 at 01:32pm.</p>
       <p align="center"><a href="#">Profile</a> | <a href="#">Logout</a></p>
 {% else %}
```

settings.py

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = "forums.UserProfile"
```

view.py

```
def login_request(request):

     username = request.POST.get("username")
     password = request.POST.get("password")

     user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
     if user is not None:
         login(request, user)
         return redirect("/")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. User must be `OneToOneField`
2. Please don't use upper letters in your field name. It is a bad practice. You must read the PEP8 (the style of coding).
3. Please remove `UserName` field in your UserProfile model because it is already define in the User model.

   ```
   class UserProfile(models.Model):
       user = models.OneToOneField(User)
       profimg = models.FileField(upload_to='images')

       def __unicode__(self):
           return "{0}".format(self.user.username)

   {% if user.is_authenticated %}
   <div class ="profile-info">
       <img src="{{ user.userprofile.profimg.url }}" width = "150" height = "150"  />
       Welcome {{ user }}               
      <p>You last logged in on Tuesday the 19th of March, 2013 at 01:32pm.</p>
      <p align="center"><a href="#">Profile</a> | <a href="#">Logout</a></p>
   {% else %}
   ............
   {% endif %}
   ```

To access user extended information in template use

```
 {{ user.userprofile.field_name }} or {{ request.user.userprofile.field_name }}
```

Then in your views

```
 request.user.get_profile().field_name
```

Comment: i tried your code but it didn't return anything. I also tried `<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ user.UserProfile.ProfImg }}" width = "150" height = "150"  />` but same result

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I will try what you have said. Ill be back for the result later.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE set correctly , you can use user.get_profile.attribute

Comment: i've tried {{ user.get_profile.ProfImg }} but it gives me an error  "Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: ProfImg, UserName

Comment: Can you show more code . I think you do not have user in the scope of the function , try request.user

Comment: no error but didn't return anything. I updated the code in my question. Username is returned when i only use {{user}}

Comment: @catherine that cannot be right, after all its accessing a python object thats it. From django's code get_profile is just implemented by AbstractUser and just fetches the model. Are you sure about this

Comment: She's using Django 1.4 not 1.5. Sorry I didn't clarify it.

Comment: ok fair enough , but still i don't see a difference in being able to fetch get_profile infact in 1.4 the function is in user class itself